# need to add '%' symbol to my float type dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x

My dataframe is as below:

```
df_sample=array([0.5, 11.3, 0., 20., 12.2, 40.4, 2.3])
```

and the output should be:

```
df_sample=array([0.5%, 11.3%, 0.%, 20.%, 12.2%, 40.4%, 2.3%])
```

Please advise

Comment: Why have you tagged this pyspark if you are using numpy arrays?

Comment: @coldspeed.. i can use either dataframes from pyspark or numpy from python.. Hence have tagged both python and pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a % to the float and keep it as a float.

You either have to send each as strings (format the number as a string with the '%'),

You could convert the array to a string array:

```
str_df_sample = [ "{}%".format(v) for v in df_sample ]
```

Or send as is. You could also just send as a float where 1.0 = 100%, .1 = 10% etc, however that is still not adding the % symbol.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate.. I can convert it to string but how to append symbols to the string.